# Only Data Transfer Out on App Service Azure

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

I have a weird problem on my azure, as I am being billed for outgoing cost. (It is not that much actually).

As I choose the free plan, for all my app services. The only cost that adds up are the Data Transfer Out Cost. After some research I found out that `The first 5GB/Month is free` as stated below from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/):

[image]

**Prediction**

These are my opinion on why the prices went up:

- Using different server, from sql and app services, but currently all my resources in one location:
  [image]
- Exceed the free 5GB / month, which is unlikely since I have just started weeks ago. Or is there a way to check how much data out being used.

Here is the billing report:

[image]

As seen here, most of the cost are made by data output. The first one which is quite high. It is a wordpress app service (this might be the reason.)

**Question**

1. How to check how much data output being used, since this might be the cause.
2. What can be the other caused that I have missed?
3. Or is this normal for the billing, as the value stated above is quite cheap.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in Monitoring capabilities at the App Service level to view your outbound data rates.

[image: App Service Monitoring Overview]

Clicking the chart will allow you to build a more customized chart of all of your outbound data transfer;

[image]

From here, you should be able to at least understand when you are using all your outbound allowance. You will probably need to dig into the code to understand why you are transferring so much data.

Hope this helps.